# If and else condtion not working in all statement jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm checking the condition with this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#uitkering_funds').hide();
  $('#uitkering_funds_hoofd').hide();
  $('#partner_uitkering').hide();
  $('#partner_uitkering_funds').hide();
  $("input[name=alleenstande],input[name=uitkering],input[name=partner_uitkering]").bind('change', function() {
      if ($("input[name=alleenstande]:checked").val() == 1 && $('input[name=uitkering]:checked').val() == 1)   {
          $("#uitkering_funds_hoofd").fadeIn(200);
          $("#partner_uitkering").hide();
          $('#partner_uitkering_funds').hide();
      } 
      else if ($("input[name=alleenstande]:checked").val() == 0 && $('input[name=uitkering]:checked').val() == 1)   {
          $("#uitkering_funds_hoofd").fadeIn(200);
          $("#partner_uitkering").hide();
          $('#partner_uitkering_funds').hide();
      }
      else if ($("input[name=alleenstande]:checked").val() == 0 && $('input[name=uitkering]:checked').val() == 0)   {
          $("#uitkering_funds_hoofd").hide();
          $("#partner_uitkering").fadeIn(200);
      }
      else if ($("input[name=alleenstande]:checked").val() == 0 && $('input[name=uitkering]:checked').val() == 0 && $('input[name=partner_uitkering]:checked').val() == 1)   {
          $("#uitkering_funds_hoofd").hide();
          $("#partner_uitkering_funds").fadeIn(200);
          alert('2');
      }
      else {
          $('#uitkering_funds').hide();
          $('#uitkering_funds_hoofd').hide();
          $('#partner_uitkering').hide();
          $('#partner_uitkering_funds').hide();
      }
  });
});
```

It is working fine with three condition, but stops working on this statement.

```
 else if ($("input[name=alleenstande]:checked").val() == 0 && $('input[name=uitkering]:checked').val() == 0 && $('input[name=partner_uitkering]:checked').val() == 1)   {
          $("#uitkering_funds_hoofd").hide();
          $("#partner_uitkering_funds").fadeIn(200);
          alert('2');
      }
```

Am i doing anything wrong here? Could please help me with this how can i this code work on all condition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then please do so. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS.

Comment: Did you try to debug it via your browser? Did you find any issue there?

Comment: No issue in console.

Comment: *"not working"* and *"stops working"* is not a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

$('input[name=partner_uitkering]:checked').val() == 1

Are you sure the value of that input name "partner_uitkering" is 1?

You should be actually taking all those 3 values into consideration while writing your conditional statements.

Comment: Yes value is 1. I double checked all the values all are correct. When i change the position of statement it works then stop other else if working.

Answer (score 0):

Your last `else if` will never evaluate since it begins with the same conditions required by the previous `else if`. Maybe consider a `switch case` statement or, as suggested by @spgk, checking the state of all inputs for each of your `if` conditions.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Some other thoughts:

Not sure which version of jQuery you are using, but

> As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on()
>   https://api.jquery.com/bind/

Also, instead of checking the `:checked` pseudo-class and hoping coercion and loose equivalencies don't do something weird, with jQuery you can just use `.prop('checked')`

Comment: how can i check the value with prop? i tried this .prop('checked').val() ==1. It did'nt work.